# Can I have non-Laravel site in Nginx when Laravel Valet is installed?

Tags: nginx, laravel-valet

I have installed Laravel Valet to use for development of Laravel projects.
Now I would like to use the Nginx installed to run Valet for other non-framework php site. Is this possible?

I tried making a file in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers` with:

```
server {
  listen       8080;
  server_name  localhost;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  root   /Users/st/Nginx;

  location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Html file can be served with this configuration, but php file gives `502 Bad Gateway`.